# How to compute a limit about exponential function?

Tags: mathematical-physics, gauge-theory

In this [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1512.08533), the operator $:Y_{i,x}:$ is defined as
$$
:Y_{i,x}~: = :~\exp\left( \sum_{p \in \mathbb{Z}} y_{i,-p} x^{p}  \right):
$$

up to some constant coefficient in (3.43) on page 13. How do you obtain the second term on the second line of (5.18) on page 20 from (5.17) (I can only obtain the first term on the second line of (5.18))?

Edit: The equations are in the following.

[image]

Comment: Would you mind adding the terms, equations and phrases in the question as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
Y_{i,ux} & \sim Y_{i,x} + :\partial_u Y_{i,ux}|_{u=1}  (u-1): \\
& = Y_{i,x} +  :Y_{i,ux} (\sum_{p \in \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}} y_{i,-p} p u^{p-1} x^p ) (u-1): \\
& = Y_{i,x} + :Y_{i,ux} (\sum_{p \in \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}} y_{i,-p} p u^{p-1} x^p )|_{u=1} (u-1): \\
& = Y_{i,x} + :Y_{i, x} (\sum_{p \in \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}} y_{i,-p} p x^p )  (u-1):\\
& = Y_{i,x} + :Y_{i, x} x \partial_x \log(Y_{i,x}) (u-1):.
\end{align}

Therefore
\begin{align}
& \lim_{u \to 1} S(u): \frac{Y_{i,ux}}{Y_{i,xq^{-1}}}( \prod_{e: i \to j} Y_{j, \mu_e^{-1} x} \prod_{e: j \to x} Y_{j, \mu_e q^{-1} x} ) : \\
& = \lim_{u \to 1} \frac{(1-q_1 u)(1- q_2u)}{(1-q u)(1-u)} ( : \frac{Y_{i, x}}{Y_{i,xq^{-1}}}( \prod_{e: i \to j} Y_{j, \mu_e^{-1} x} \prod_{e: j \to x} Y_{j, \mu_e q^{-1} x} ) : \\
& + : \frac{Y_{i, x}}{Y_{i,xq^{-1}}}( \prod_{e: i \to j} Y_{j, \mu_e^{-1} x} \prod_{e: j \to x} Y_{j, \mu_e q^{-1} x} ) x \partial_x \log(Y_{i,x}) (u-1) : ) \\
& = \lim_{u \to 1} \frac{(1-q_1 u)(1- q_2u)}{(1-q u)(1-u)}  : \frac{Y_{i, x}}{Y_{i,xq^{-1}}}( \prod_{e: i \to j} Y_{j, \mu_e^{-1} x} \prod_{e: j \to x} Y_{j, \mu_e q^{-1} x} ) : \\
& \quad - \frac{(1-q_1 )(1- q_2 )}{(1-q ) }  : \frac{Y_{i, x}}{Y_{i,xq^{-1}}}( \prod_{e: i \to j} Y_{j, \mu_e^{-1} x} \prod_{e: j \to x} Y_{j, \mu_e q^{-1} x} ) x \partial_x \log(Y_{i,x}):
\end{align}

\begin{align}
& \lim_{u \to 1} S(u^{-1}): \frac{Y_{i, x}}{Y_{i,uxq^{-1}}}( \prod_{e: i \to j} Y_{j, u\mu_e^{-1} x} \prod_{e: j \to x} Y_{j, u\mu_e q^{-1} x} ) : \\
& = \lim_{u \to 1} \frac{(1-q_1 u^{-1})(1- q_2u^{-1})}{(1-q u^{-1})(1-u^{-1})}: \frac{Y_{i, x}}{Y_{i,xq^{-1}} + :Y_{i, xq^{-1}} x \partial_x \log(Y_{i,xq^{-1}}) (u-1):} \\
& ( \prod_{e: i \to j} (Y_{j, \mu_e^{-1} x} + :Y_{j, x\mu_e q^{-1} } x \partial_x \log(Y_{j,x\mu_e q^{-1}}) (u-1):)  \prod_{e: j \to i} (Y_{j, \mu_e q^{-1} x} + :Y_{j, x\mu_e q^{-1} } x \partial_x \log(Y_{j,x\mu_e q^{-1}}) (u-1):) : \\
& = \lim_{u \to 1} \frac{(1-q_1 u^{-1})(1- q_2u^{-1})}{(1-q u^{-1})(1-u^{-1})}: \frac{Y_{i, x}}{Y_{i,xq^{-1}}} (1 - x \partial_x \log(Y_{i,xq^{-1}}) (u-1)) \\
&   \prod_{e: i \to j}  Y_{j, \mu_e^{-1} x} (1 + x \partial_x \log(Y_{j,x\mu_e q^{-1}}) (u-1) )   \prod_{e: j \to i}  Y_{j, \mu_e q^{-1} x}(1 + x \partial_x \log(Y_{j,x\mu_e q^{-1}}) (u-1) ) : \\
& \sim \lim_{u \to 1} \frac{(1-q_1 u^{-1})(1- q_2u^{-1})}{(1-q u^{-1})(1-u^{-1})}: \frac{Y_{i, x}}{Y_{i,xq^{-1}}} (1 - x \partial_x \log(Y_{i,xq^{-1}}) (u-1)) \\
&   (\prod_{e: i \to j}  Y_{j, \mu_e^{-1} x}) (1 + x \partial_x \sum_{e: i \to j} \log(Y_{j,x\mu_e q^{-1}}) (u-1) )   (\prod_{e: j \to i}  Y_{j, \mu_e q^{-1} x}) (1 + \sum_{e: j \to i} x \partial_x \log(Y_{j,x\mu_e q^{-1}}) (u-1) ) : \\
& = \lim_{u \to 1} \frac{(1-q_1 u^{-1})(1- q_2u^{-1})}{(1-q u^{-1})(1-u^{-1})}: \frac{Y_{i, x}}{Y_{i,xq^{-1}}} (1 - x \partial_x \log(Y_{i,xq^{-1}}) (u-1)) \\
&   (\prod_{e: i \to j}  Y_{j, \mu_e^{-1} x}) (1 + x \partial_x  \log \prod_{e: i \to j} (Y_{j,x\mu_e q^{-1}}) (u-1) )   (\prod_{e: j \to i}  Y_{j, \mu_e q^{-1} x}) (1 +  x \partial_x \log \prod_{e: j \to i} (Y_{j,x\mu_e q^{-1}}) (u-1) ) : \\
& \sim \lim_{u \to 1} \frac{(1-q_1 u^{-1})(1- q_2u^{-1})}{(1-q u^{-1})(1-u^{-1})}: \frac{Y_{i, x}}{Y_{i,xq^{-1}}} \prod_{e: i \to j}  Y_{j, \mu_e^{-1} x} \prod_{e: j \to i}  Y_{j, \mu_e q^{-1} x} \\
& - \frac{(1-q_1 )(1- q_2 )}{(1-q ) }   x \partial_x ( \log(Y_{i,xq^{-1}}) - \log \prod_{e: i \to j} Y_{i, \mu_e^{-1} x} - \log \prod_{e: j \to i}  Y_{j, \mu_e q^{-1} x} ) \\
& \sim \lim_{u \to 1} \frac{(1-q_1 u^{-1})(1- q_2u^{-1})}{(1-q u^{-1})(1-u^{-1})}: \frac{Y_{i, x}}{Y_{j,xq^{-1}}} \prod_{e: i \to j}  Y_{j, \mu_e^{-1} x} \prod_{e: j \to i}  Y_{j, \mu_e q^{-1} x} \\
& - \frac{(1-q_1 )(1- q_2 )}{(1-q ) }   x \partial_x \log  \frac{Y_{i,xq^{-1}} }{\prod_{e: i \to j} Y_{j, \mu_e^{-1} x} Y_{j, \mu_e q^{-1} x} }.
\end{align}

Therefore we obtain (5.18) in the paper.